Calculate Distance to the nearest object
I need to make a map of distances to the nearest object.
I have a solution where i am looping over every point of a map, and every object, calculating the distance to all of them, and then leaving only minimum distance.
The problem here is that if I am woking with real data, the map can easily contain 10s of millions of points, and there can be more than 100 objects.
Is there any better code implementation for solving this problem?
Loading packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Generate synthetic map
coord_dict = {"X": [],
              "Y": []}

for x_value in range(0, 10000, 50):    
    for y_value in range(0, 5000, 50):
        coord_dict["X"].append(x_value)
        coord_dict["Y"].append(y_value)

map_df = pd.DataFrame(coord_dict)

Generate points to calculate distance from
well_points_dict = {"X": [500, 1500, 4000, 5500, 6250, 7500, 8000, 9000], 
                    "Y": [500, 4000, 2000, 1500, 500, 5000, 100, 2500]}

wells_df = pd.DataFrame(well_points_dict)

Calculate distances
calculations_count = 0
distance_map = np.zeros(map_df.shape)

for i in range(map_df.shape[0]):
    d = []
    for j in range(wells_df.shape[0]):
        d.append(((map_df["X"].iloc[i]-wells_df["X"][j])**2 + (map_df["Y"].iloc[i]-      wells_df["Y"][j])**2)**0.5)
        calculations_count += 1
    dd = min(d)
    distance_map[i,1] = dd
    # print(calculations_count)

Print resulting map
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(x=map_df["X"],y=map_df["Y"],c=distance_map[:,1],s=1,cmap='terrain')
for i in range(len(wells_df)):
    plt.plot(wells_df["X"][i],wells_df["Y"][i], color='black', marker='o',markersize=3)
plt.title('Calculated map')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.colorbar(shrink=0.25)

Result map example:


"Leaving only the minimum distance" -- Distance of what?  If you want the minimum distance from every point to every other point, then you have no choice but to try them all, as you are doing.

@TimRoberts this is very much not true. In one dimension, you can sort the array. In higher dimensions, something like a k-tree gives you a rough analogue, and there are many approximations.

Only had a quick look so you might already be doing this, just make sure your not calculating x->y and y->x

KDTree is what you are looking for, there is an implementation of it in scipy.spatial.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import spatial

Given your trial points:
x_value = np.arange(0, 10000, 50)  
y_value = np.arange(0, 5000, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_value, y_value)
points = np.stack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T

And well points:
x_well = np.array([500, 1500, 4000, 5500, 6250, 7500, 8000, 9000])
y_well = np.array([500, 4000, 2000, 1500, 500, 5000, 100, 2500])
wells = np.stack([x_well, y_well]).T

We can create a KDTree:
interpolator = spatial.KDTree(wells)

And query efficiently the tree to get distances and also indices of which point it is closer:
distances, indices = interpolator.query(points)
# 7.12 ms ± 711 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 30 runs, 100 loops each)

Plotting the result leads to:
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.scatter(*points.T, marker=".", c=distances)
axe.scatter(*wells.T, color="black")
axe.grid()


We see the Voronoi diagram appearing on the color map which is a good confirmation distances are correctly interpreted wrt reference points (wells):
voronoi = spatial.Voronoi(wells)
# ...
spatial.voronoi_plot_2d(voronoi, ax=axe)


Where the object Voronoi is the Voronoi diagram based on your reference points (wells) and voronoi_plot_2d an helper to draw it on axes.

Thank you! That worked great! Didn't know about the KDTree=)

(Approximate) nearest neighbours search is a common task with a ton of libraries. A handy place to check is https://ann-benchmarks.com/ — the best choice depends on your needs, but if you really have 2d data with tons of points a simple k-d tree is likely to speed up querying dramatically while still giving exact answers. In higher dimensions, you’ll probably need to give up on guaranteed exact answers, but relaxing that a little bit can give you huge speed wins.
